# Crontab timezone issue. Need to run a script using cron tab in Indian Standard Time. But the server time is MST

Tags: linux, cron

I am using a shared server on with following specificattion

> Linux version 2.6.32-604.30.3.lve1.3.63.el6.x86_64
>   (mockbuild@build.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat
>   4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sun Sep 27 06:34:10 EDT 2015

When I run date command, shown as follows. That is server's time zone is MST, that is GMT-7.

> @ [~]$ date  Fri Apr 15 01:42:24 MST 2016

I want to run crontab on daily at 5 AM indian time[Asia/Kolkata] this server.

So set crontab as follows:

```
CRON_TZ=IST 

0 5 * * * php my_file.php
```

But still the file executed in server time 5 AM, which is 12.30 hours earlier than I needed.

Hope you understand my requirement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This really depends on the system you are running. See [how to run cron jobs on GMT not local time?](http://superuser.com/q/248841/204979) -> _Not all versions of cron support running jobs using a time zone other than the system's_

Comment: The easiest way to achieve your goal is by adjusting the time in your command.. Like in your case, you can use 30 17 * * * php my_file.php

Answer (score 3):

You could try setting the variable `TZ='IST'` instead of `CRON_TZ='IST'`. Also, After making changes to this daemon's config file you need to restart it:

```
service cron restart
```

**Alternativly,** In `cron.conf` or `/etc/default/cron`:

```
export TZ='IST'
```

You can use full name of indian timezone:

```
export TZ='Asia/Kolkata'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out on Ubuntu 14/16. Worked perfectly for me.

Steps (sudo implied):

1. `cat /etc/timezone`
2. `rm -fv /etc/localtime`
3. `ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata /etc/localtime`
4. `apt install -y --reinstall tzdata`
5. `/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart`
6. `tail -f /var/log/syslog`
7. `cat /etc/timezone`